# Can a maximally consistent set be infinite?

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus, model-theory

This is the definition of a maximally consistent set from Logic and Structure by Van Dalen

> A set Γ is maximally consistent iff
>
> (a) Γ is consistent,
>
> (b) Γ ⊆ Γ ′ and Γ ′ consistent ⇒ Γ = Γ ′.
>
> Remark. One could replace (b) by (b’): if Γ is a proper subset of Γ ′,
> then Γ ′ is inconsistent. I.e., by just throwing in one extra
> proposition, the set becomes inconsistent.

This, at first, made me assume that Γ, in this case, must be finite, since a new formula can't be added. But a colleague told me that, for example, the set for every theorem is maximally consistent and infinite. Is that true?

Comment: I don't think a non-empty maximally consistent set can be finite.  If $\phi$ is a sentence in it then $\phi\land\phi$, $\phi \land\phi\land\phi$ and so on are in it.

Comment: This is true. You can computably enumerate all the theorems of say, propositional logic, and this will be an infinite set. You can also have an infinite consistent set that is not maximally consistent. Just consider the set of formulas in first-order logic (I'm leaving out the quantifiers), $\{(x=x), (x=x\wedge x=x), (x=x\wedge x=x\wedge x=x),\ldots\}$.

Comment: The body of your post should clarify what kind of things (formulas, statements, etc.) are allowed to belong to the set $\Gamma$.  Context of a text on Logic and Structure suggests the elements are some kind of logical expressions, but to make the claim provable by reasoned argument, a definition is required (esp. what makes the set $\Gamma$ finite vs. infinite).